# Angular ng-hide doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I'm facing a problem with Angular. My code is simple but ng-hide doesn't work. I want to hide a part of the code when a button of the sign up form has been modified by user. Could you help me?

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="signUpForm" ng-submit="signUpFormSubmit(signUpForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email address *" name="signUpEmail">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo *" name="signUpPseudo">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password *" name="signUpPassword">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Sign Up</button>
    <div ng-hide="signUpForm.signUpEmail.$pristine || signUpForm.signUpPseudo.$pristine || signUpForm.signUpPassword.$pristine">
        <hr>
        <div class="padding-horizontal">
             <h4 class="center">You already have an account?</h4>

            <button class="button button-block button-stable">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is a JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9ce63mno/3/

UPDATE: although I don't know why a controller is needed in this case, I added one. Also I defined ng-app.

Thank you

Comment: demo doesn't have any `ng-app`  ... what are we supposed to see there without angular being bootstrapped?

Comment: please try to provide a more complete, verifiable example of your issue.  without `ng-app` and `ng-controller`, `ng-hide` has no meaning at all.

Comment: additionally, look into the `ng-model` directive. Read about it here: [angularJS doc on Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). Give it another shot. GL!

Comment: and another thing: use the SO searchbox at the top of this page - its really helpful - search for something akin to `[angularjs] form hide pristine` and you're bound to find similar questions/answers. If you figure out a solution, post your answer as a possible solution, read [meta: etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently it is because there is no ng-model defined for the form fields.